# swift json type data parsing after get data

Tags: json, swift, subscript

I'm developing a function which is receiving some JSON after calling a `NSURLRequest` in Swift. I am having issues accessing the different data values with subscript after I have parsed the result.

---

The following is the retrieved JSON:

```
{"retCode":100,"retMsg":"Success","retData":{"usn":92,"id":"clipsys@gmail.com","nickname":"ppigimi","profile_image":"..\/upload\/profile\/20150528172839.jpeg","language":"jp","join_channel_nm":"korfolk","cert_key":"696D6FB453DC141E5295E9D8E37B8DD0F1AFC8E34CE30B74551ED74A447AC564","cert_flag":"Y","join_date":"20150518155650","token":"3ea0a5fec1b55a5a23b5f1dc5c14b040dcd71eea"}}
```

---

The following is my code. I don't know how to get the values `usn` and `token` inside of `retData`.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    // You can print out response object
    println("response = \(response)")

    // Print out response body
    let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("responseString = \(responseString)")

    //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

    var err: NSError?
    var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary


    if let parseJSON = myJSON as? [String: AnyObject] {
        // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
        var retCode = parseJSON["retCode"] as? Int
        println("retCode: \(retCode)")

        if let retData = parseJSON["retData"] as? [AnyObject] {
            for data in retData {
                /**let usn = data["usn"]

                println("USN = \(usn)")**/ 
            }
        }

        if retCode == 100 {
            //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("usn", forKey: String)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "AAAAAA", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                action in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
            }

            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
        });
    }    
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accessing `retCode` as `[AnyObject]`. It is not an `Array`, but actually a JSON object. You will need to cast it to a `Dictionay`, for example `[String : AnyObject]`.

This means that your `for` loop where you are accessing the data can look something like the following:

```
if let retData = parseJSON["retData"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
    for data in retData {
        println("data is: \(data)")
        /**let usn = data["usn"]
        println("USN = \(usn)")**/
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer to your question was helpful and was fulfilling, then please accept it as the answer to your post to indicate towards other users that your issue has been resolved :)
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work